# Runnning Express server by GitHub action

Tags: node.js, express, github, workflow, github-actions

I do not know whether I am right or wrong. But I am here trying to run the server by using Github action.

main.js

```
const app = express()

const PORT = 3636;

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log('App running on port ',PORT)
})

app.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send("welcome")
})
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve":"node main.js"
  },
```

/.github/workflows/node.js.yml

[image]

But the job is not going to complete, it will be in progressing state. I need to cancel the workflow manually.

[image]

Can I know the what is the reason for this?

Comment: How do you expect this to "complete"? Your webserver is running, it will _never_ complete (i.e. run to completion).

Comment: Just in case, GitHub Actions is not meant to be used as the thing running your application. You probably want to run your tests with GitHub Actions to make sure every change you make to your application passes the tests.